# What's the best word/label to put on a multitask button?

Tags: buttons, naming, multitasking

We have a web app. It currently has a button which opens a modal window. This modal window has quite a lot of functions in it. Here they are:

- Generate a PDF of the selected products (the most important function)
- Print
- Share on social media / email (4 buttons)
- QR code

The button's current name is "Send" which makes no sense in my opinion. The other suggested name was "Share" but it's not always relevant. I think "Export" might be the best way to go with it but I would appreciate some more suggestions.

PS: I know the multitask button is not the best UX idea, but it's the business decision...

Comment: Even a business decision should be made on the basis on good information and sound logic... I hope there is some testing planned to show that a better result can be achieved via other designs.

Answer (score 1):

Since all of these buttons directly or indirectly enable a user to move the information (of the selected products) offsite, be it physically or electronically, I would call this button **"export"**

Export would cover Generating a PDF and printing and the QR Code. Personally I would expect social media sharing and email to be under a different category so I would consider maybe rethinking your information architecture there.